# Database authentication

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I have issue with database authentication. We have a database on AWS database and application uses this database and we have different users who uses the application. There are several components on application which use database by logg in to database. And My concern is that what is best way to secure login details from application to database and condition is that login details should not be stored any where. 
I have thought that we can use single username and password for logging in to database from application but may not be secured enough. Or, changing the username and password in certain interval of time. But I dont have any idea how to that as we are not allowed to store sql server login details. 
Could anyone advise me better way to secure the sql server login details from my application to AWS database server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is deploying plain-text credentials to your instance, you can use the KMS to eliminate this.

Basically, you would encrypt your database connection string, and then at run-time use KMS to decrypt it.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your advise.  I am working as intern database developer so I don't have a lot of idea. And my development team trying  make me to find out whether is it possible to create different login details for AWS database from application for different user. If  you have any idea  please share.Thanks.